# Not able to loop XML using Xpath using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Not able to understand why my simple xpath does not work on the below XML.

I need to find the node "deployment" and delete the childnode and then add a new child node. Should be pretty easy, but no, there is something with the XML that makes it not possible for my code to find the deployment-node by simply selecting it by its name.

The XML (Clickonce .Net XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="PublishDev.app" version="3.1.0.182" publicKeyToken="38f29cb66cf790f2" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="KLP" asmv2:product="PublishDev" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true">
    <subscription>
      <update>
        <expiration maximumAge="0" unit="days" />
      </update>
    </subscription>
    <deploymentProvider codebase="http://nrs.dev/NrsClient/PublishDev.application" />
  </deployment>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.7" profile="Client" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
    <framework targetVersion="4.7" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="ApplicationFiles\PublishDev_3_1_0_182\PublishDev.exe.manifest" size="48466">
      <assemblyIdentity name="PublishDev.exe" version="3.1.0.182" publicKeyToken="38f29cb66cf790f2" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>zbbwOLiL12PznwEX7G3FGhmU8R0=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Then to loop the XML using Powershell

```
function loopXml{
    param(
        $nodes
    )
    write-host "*************************  Loop my xml********************* "
    foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        Write-host $node.toString()
    }
}

$deployManifestFullPath = "D:\temp\stripped.xml"

$sourcexml = [xml](get-content $deployManifestFullPath);
$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("deployment")
loopXml $nodes 

$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("//*", $ns)
loopXml $nodes
```

The output

```
*************************  Loop my xml*********************
*************************  Loop my xml*********************
assembly
assemblyIdentity
description
deployment
subscription
update
expiration
deploymentProvider
compatibleFrameworks
framework
framework
dependency
dependentAssembly
assemblyIdentity
hash
Transforms
Transform
DigestMethod
DigestValue
```

I do not understand why the line

```
$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("deployment")
```

does not return the deployment-node. When I select the whole document it is there, but ... well, need some help to figure out this one.

Ref. [w3schools XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) just adding the name of the node should select all nodes with that name. In my case, the single node named deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("deployment")
```

to

```
$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("//*[name()='deployment']")
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick...

Confused since W3CSchools says this shold work:

nodename Selects all nodes with the name "nodename"

But - won't spend to much time on that, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: asmv1:assembly. Line 40, position 14."

You are missing something like this at the bottom of the xml:

```
</asmv1:assembly>
```

If you indented properly `$sourcexml.save('stripped.xml')`, you would see that deployment is not the top level node. There's also the namespace problem.

You can get the `$nodes` this way.  There's only one.  I don't know namespaces:

```
$nodes = $sourcexml.assembly.deployment
$nodes 


install subscription deploymentProvider
------- ------------ ------------------
true    subscription deploymentProvider
```

Hmm, this works:

```
select-xml asmv1:assembly stripped.xml -Namespace @{asmv1='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1'}


Node     Path                           Pattern
----     ----                           -------
assembly /Users/js/foo/stripped.xml     asmv1:assembly
```

But not this:

```
select-xml '//deployment' stripped.xml -Namespace @{asmv1='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1'}
```

Ugh.  This works.  The `x` could be anything.  It can't be `xmlns`.

```
select-xml '//x:deployment' stripped.xml -Namespace @{x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2'}  


Node       Path                           Pattern
----       ----                           -------
deployment /Users/js/foo/stripped.xml     //x:deployment
```

And finally the selectnodes() version with the namespace.  You need the `//` to search subnodes, because deployment is not the top level node.  Having a namespace makes it more tricky.  `x` represents the default namespace here.

```
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$nsmgr = $sourcexml.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('x','urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2')
$nodes = $sourcexml.selectnodes('//x:deployment', $nsmgr)
$nodes


install subscription deploymentProvider
------- ------------ ------------------
true    subscription deploymentProvider
```

Comment: Sorry for that, it was just a simple editing issue - the closing tag was not indented enough, and therefore it was not showing. have updated the code so now it should be just fine.

Comment: But - yes deployment is not top level node, but 

$nodes = $sourcexml.SelectNodes("deployment")

is valid xpath if I'm not totally mistaken. It should find any node named deployment anywhere in the document.

Comment: It would be `$sourcexml.SelectNodes("//deployment")`.  But there's a namespace too.